# Show Javascript popup on OnAuthorization Code

Tags: asp.net, http, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to show the Javascript popup alert message rather than redirect the page on UnAuthorised page. Any idea what to do? below is my code

```
   public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
            {
                var detail = context.ActionDescriptor;
    
                //Create permission string based on the requested controller name and action name in the format 'controllername-action'
                string requiredPermission = String.Format("{0}-{1}", detail.RouteValues["controller"], detail.RouteValues["action"]);
    
                RBACUser user = new RBACUser(context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name,AppInfo.ConnectionInfo());
                //Check if the requesting user has the permission to run the controller's action
                if (!user.HasPermission(requiredPermission) & !user.IsSysAdmin)
                {   
                    context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Index" }, { "controller", "Unauthorised" } });
                }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, if you do not redirect to a page, how do you alert the js?

Comment: I did redirection on unauthorized page and I am able to show popup also . Only problem now shared layout display on background